# invisible captcha

Tags: captcha

I'm using the following security(invisble captcha) for my site's form submission to prevent auto submission:

1. generate the result of md5 with a fixed salt on number x and render it
   inside the form as a hidden field
2. generate 2 hidden fields a and b where a + b = x,  a and b are
   unencrypted
3. upon submission, use javascript to add another plain hidden field c
   where c=a+b
4. on server side apply md5 on c with the salt, compare it with encrypted
   x

However such system is cracked in production, one person was able to auto-submit thousands of forms successfully.  Any idea how?

One way to do it is, the hacker already knows that the operation is + (simple to find out by observation of javascript), read the form and add a and b, create a new form with the extra c field where c=a+b.  He has to first read a form, then create one for submission.

My questions are:

1. Is the hypothesis I presented above the likely way to break my system?
2. If so, what should I do to prevent this kind of hack?
3. What are other alternative hacks the hacker might use?

I don't want to use real captcha because it degrades user experience.  All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, the hacker could just *execute your javascript themselves*.

If you want to validate that the user isn't a robot, you'll have to get the user to do something a robot can't. It's really that simple.

Answer (score 1):

A further step would be to increase the amount of computation required; make it infeasible to submit the forms too rapidly.  Try looking at [HashCash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash#Blogs).

Answer (score 0):

I can't give advice in your specific case, but Django has some nice approaches, how spam in comment fields could be supressed without captchas: [Nice approaches here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/comments/#id1).

Answer (score 0):

Your system is not working because the attacker(s) are just executing your JavaScript themselves. If you want to use a somewhat similar scheme that will prevent automated submissions you need to put a workload factor on the client. This will not stop the automated software from being able to submit to your site but it will slow them down and increase the cost of an attack. The goal is to increase the cost and slow them down enough that the attack is just not worthwhile. Instead of trying to build it yourself try using [this proof of work service](https://www.spamcaptcher.com/captcha/faq.jsp#what_is_proof_of_work).